# Laravel How to compare an input array collection with the array collection selected from the database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I really need assistance with an issues i have been having for a week. i do have an invoice form 
[image]
of which i could add multiple items in an array to store in the database

```
<?php
   $arrayNumber = 0;
      for($x = 1; $x < 4; $x++) { ?>
     <tr id="row<?php echo $x; ?>" class="orderItem  <?php echo $arrayNumber; ?>">
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="productName[]" id="productName<?php echo $x; ?>" onchange="getProductData(<?php echo $x; ?>)" required>
                    <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                    @foreach($stocks as $stock)
                        <option value="{{$stock->id}}">{{$stock->abbr}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                <input type="number" name="rate[]" id="rate<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required/>                             
                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="rateValue[]" id="rateValue<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"  required/>   -->
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity<?php echo $x; ?>" onkeyup="getTotal(<?php echo $x ?>)" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" min="1" required/>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                <input type="text" name="total[]" id="total<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />                                
                <input type="hidden" name="totalValue[]" id="totalValue<?php echo $x; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />    
            </div>
        </td>
        <th>
            <button class="btn btn-default removeProductRowBtn" type="button" id="removeProductRowBtn" onclick="removeProductRow(<?php echo $x; ?>)">
                <i class="icofont icofont-minus"></i>
            </button>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php
$arrayNumber++;
} // /for
?>
```

storing in the db  as

```
$data = $request->all();

    $productName = count($data['productName']);
    for($i=0; $i < $productName; $i++){

        $stt = new StockTransferTransaction;

        $stt->stock_id = $data['productName'][$i];
        $stt->rate = $data['rate'][$i];


        $stt->quantity = $data['quantity'][$i];
        $stt->valuation = $data['totalValue'][$i];
        $stt->stock_transfer_id = $id;
        $stt->save();

        // go to stock

        $stock = Stock::where('id', $productName)->get();

        dd($stock);

        // save all
        $quantityApproval->save();
        $stock->save();
    }
```

Which is successful

Here is the issue i would like make some checks from another table like maybe if the quantity in request is more that what is in that table then returns an error before saving to the database before saving to the database

with my effort i used a

```
$data = $request->all();

    $productName = count($data['productName']);
    for($i=0; $i < $productName; $i++){

    $stock = Stock::select('quantity')->whereIn('id', $data['productName'])->get();
     // $stock = Stock::find($data['productName']);
     dd($stock, $request->all());
    }
```

[image]

and dont know how to compare the request array and the collection result for at least the quantity to return a response. Please i need help badly. Anybody here, Somebody, anybody. Thanks alot

Comment: First you count the amount of your products in `$productName = count($data['productName']);` and later you use the count as an ID to fetch a product from DB: `$stock = Stock::where('id', $productName)->get();`. Doesn't seems correct.

Comment: thanks but the $productName  are individual Stock_ids to relate individually in the Stock itself to fetch the quantity. i want to get the $product name individually, compare and subtract. Thank i would appreciate your response

Comment: The individual stock items are inside `$data['productName']`, but you store the count of the items to `$productName` and use it to fetch an item from database. It should be `$stock = Stock::where('id', $data['productName'][$i])->get();`.

Comment: Lets use your code and go through it. The array `$data['productName']` contains three items (as i your image): 46, 8, 23.

You count and store the amount of items with `$productName = count($data['productName']);`, so `$productName` is `3`. You then use the variable as a exit condition in your for loop. So far nothing wrong. But then you use the amount of your products `3` as an ID to fetch your stock item from the db, which will be the one with ID 3. If `$data['productName']` holds four items, you will fetch the stock item with ID 4 and so on.

Comment: it only fetches one if i did get you right. but please could you assist with the code if you dont mind..  $productName = count($data['productName']);
        for($i=0; $i < $productName; $i++){
            $stock = Stock::where('id', $data['productName'][$i])->get();
            dd($stock);
        }

Comment: I would like to but I do not really understand what you try to archive. Your code needs major refactoring, your variables naming is complete misleading like `$stt->stock_id = $data['productName'][$i]` (why is the ID of a stock is inside an array called `productName`), where the `$id` comes from in `$stt->stock_transfer_id = $id;`? Your Blade file is a mix of plain PHP and Blade. Why?

Comment: okay i had to achieve the first image using the for loop function. there is an add row beneath the form of which javascript that handles the next row added and is all working fine and i have their naming values as quantity[] productname[]/ stock_id[], rate[], total[] all collects their values to the controller. they are meant to save to db and its working fine but to validate the stock quantity individually and subtract from the Stock id itself is my issue. if you see the image above it just a clear visual example and am on a deadline

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you want to compare between existing and new items.
In my opinion, you should store an md5 for your items in database. Then you can convert items of your request as an md5 too.

```
md5(collection) = md5(request)
```

Comment: Pheara am not comparing if collection and request are correct  or if values are correct am trying to check quantity in the input of the request item to the the collection if its more or lesser you could kindly enter the three image descriptions in the question article. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to check all your listed products and count the number for each entry and compare that. If any single entry quantity is higher, you need to throw an error.

You can write by following way:

```
$data = $request->all();

foreach ($data['productName'] as $key => $productName) {
    $stock = Stock::select('quantity')->where('id', $data['productName'])->first();

    if ($stock->quantity > $data['quantity'][$key]) {
        return back()->with('error', 'Quantity is bigger that stock amount');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @savon. But the $stock = Stock::select('quantity')->where('id', $data['productName'])->first(); validates only the first quantity on the request input to the the database quantity instead i want the three to be validated. if i remove the first(); it provides an eloquent error. I appreciate your response

Comment: @KomolafeSchneider it's a loop. So, you are counting 1 product at a time. This will validate all the three.